# Automatic Sliding text

Tags: jquery, slide

I have the following piece of jquery code to slide different set of text which is wrapped to specific div like `slide0`, `slide1` etc.

```
function startSlider() {
    $('#slide0').show("fade", 500);
    $('#slide0').delay(5500).hide("slide", 500);

    var slider_count = $(".slides").size();
    var count = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#slide' + count).show("slide", {direction: 'right'}, 500);
        $('#slide' + count).delay(3000).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);

        if (count == slider_count) {
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }``
    }, 3000);
}
```

The problem is after sliding the last text say in div `slide5` there is a gap to show the first slide say `slide0`. How to remove this timing gap and display the text in a continuous slide show

Comment: Please create a fiddle to show your problem.

Comment: if i understand what you are saying, have you try to `setInterval` to execute the slide every x amount of time, and some `var i` to keep track of which one it has been played..